# Cannot access injected services inside of directive link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to add a factory to an existing directive. Right now the feature is still being worked out, and I am still fairly new with angular but strong with JS. In terms of general JS scope, everything seems like it should be fine. But, equipment and remoteTerminalFactory don't exist when it gets into the link function. I added a variable before the return, and that is also no longer there. It has to be some kind of scope issue, but I don't understand what would be causing the problem.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('App')
   .directive('modalRemoteTerminal', ['equipment', 'remoteTerminalFactory',      function (equipment, remoteTerminalFactory) {
    var test = true;
     // equipment & remoteTerminalFactory exist as expected
     return {
       templateUrl: 'app/equipment-detail/health-tab/modal-remote-terminal/remote-terminal.html',
       restrict: 'E',
       link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        // test, equipment & remoteTerminalFactory are undefined
        scope.modalCtrlRemoteTerminal = {};
        scope.remoteTerminal = function(){ 
        scope.modalCtrlRemoteTerminal.openModal();
        };
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: `equipment` and `remoteTerminalFactory` should be defined in your link function. Can you show the code that is not working?

Comment: I don't have any code there currently because I cannot access the factory I injected. As I understand it, you don't define that in the link function as it is already done in the directive. Shouldn't I have access to those three variables called out in the comments inside the link function?

Comment: yes you will have access to those three variables in the link function. try reproducing your problem in a plunkr

Answer (score 1):

There are several basic things that must be implemented in order to access angular factory.

Please see this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cnn1IybN2RWDhwOTNXrM?p=preview), I've put your directive inside angular app, and created mock factories.

Here are main points:

- instantiate services (mock factories in our case)

  ```
  angular.module('App').factory('equipment', function () {
     return {
        tellSomething: function(text){
          console.log(text)
        }
     };
  });
  ...
  ```
- inject services into directive (this part looks fine in your code snippet), try to use service method in order to test

  ```
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      //showing the access to injected factories/services
      equipment.tellSomething("I'm equipment factory");
      remoteTerminalFactory.tellSomething("I'm remoteTerminalFactory factory");
      ...
  ```
- make sure all angular files are imported into `index.html` in right order (the main thing is to import file with app instantiation first)

  ```
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="service.js"></script>
  <script src="directive.js"></script>
  ```
- use your custom directive in `index.html`

  ```
  <body ng-app="App">
     <h2>Angular app</h2>
     <hr>
     <modal-remote-terminal></modal-remote-terminal>
  </body>
  ```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cnn1IybN2RWDhwOTNXrM?p=preview) for more details. You'll see that test methods from factories are executed, which means that services are accessible.